# Cross platform millisecond timer lasting more than 49 days?

Tags: c++, c, dedicated-server

I'm going to be developing a small dedicated server in C/C++ that will require uptime of forever.  I've been looking into some time functions as millisecond timing is required for calculations.  I have 2 problems that I'm facing:

1. Using a 32bit integer to store the number of milliseconds since the operation began will wrap around at about the 49 days mark resetting to zero.  I have thought about using 64 bit integers, using gettimeofday to retrieve microseconds but this brings me to the second part.
2. There doesn't seem to be any standard system calls for getting elapsed milliseconds that are platform independant

What should I do to resolve both these issues?

Comment: Forgive me if this is stating the blindingly obvious, but 1) use more bits 2) write a system dependent module for making the best of whatever time primitive you have.

Comment: "require uptime of forever" -- Even reboots aren't allowed? What about water leaking on the server or a power cut? Will the hatch in LOST blow up and the world ends?

Comment: @Coronatus: With more context: "a...server in C/C++ that will require uptime of forever". The software still has to be developed with the assumption that the hardware will go arbitrarily long without a reboot/malfunction/meteorite impact, yes? Otherwise, you're essentially saying "this software must be rebooted every X days", which is obviously a bad plan.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Use a 64bit integer, presuming that gives you enough time
2. You are correct; there is no standard.  One possibility would be to use the [Boost DateTime](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/doc/html/date_time.html) library, alternately find another or roll your own.

Good Luck!

Comment: +1 for the Boost/DateTime reference. **boost::posix_time::ptime** is amazing. You really should try it.

Comment: In case 500 million years isnt enough, you could always use a 128bit integer

Answer (score 2):

As has already been said, the first problem you are going to confront is going to obtain a reliable millisecond-precise time.

I admit I am a bit phased by the question though.

I can understand the need for precise timing (millisecond level, even microsecond) but timing a 50days at a millisecond level seems... strange.

You should perhaps review your need first, but it is rare to need more than 6 or 7 significant digits... and I am afraid that you are trying to get a one size fit them all duration object.

Perhaps that you should instead classify your durations:

- a few minutes at most > use millisecond precision
- otherwise > use second precision (the famous count since Jan 1st 1970)

Because... what is the sense of 1/10 second at the scale of 2 months ?

Answer (score 0):

Obvious. Use 64-bit integers with platform-specific code to get the number of milliseconds. On Unix including OSX, you want `gettimeofday`. On Windows, good luck getting a reliable millisecond-granularity time source; the [code in the Tcl library to do this](http://tcl.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/tcl/tcl/win/tclWinTime.c?revision=1.36&view=markup) is really complex as there are some evil gotchas in the area.

Answer (score 0):

answer to 1: If the "millisecond timing" that you are measuring is under around 20 days, you can subtract the times as unsigned values and check the result as signed value.  This should give the right result with wrapping timers (wrapping from 0xffffffff to 0x00000000).  If your timing is over 20 days, you need more bits.

Comment: 24.85513480902777777777777777777_ days would be the maximum measurable time delta.
You can usually code things so that you can avoid ever calculating such long spans of time.  Never setting a timer that is longer than about 12 days is one good idea.  Another would be if you do need to record a time that could become longer than that work out a way to have a flag that says if that time is old or not.  Old here being that it has been around at least as long as the span of time which you can trust.